# Excel does not update formulas values after filling source cells with values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I do 3 steps:

1. Based on a template, **I create a new Excel file through code** (it works fine):

   ```
   Shared Sub FillExcel()
   Dim extension As String = ".xlsx"
   Dim sourcePath As String = "c:\Temp\libro" & extension
   Dim targetPath As String = "c:\Temp\libro - " & DateTime.Now.Hour & DateTime.Now.Minute & extension

   'Generar archivo nuevo a partir del anterior
   FileIO.FileSystem.CopyFile(sourcePath, targetPath, True)
   ```

The template has two sheets:

"Circuito1$", which I will fill with values

"Formula$", where I have a formula that summarizes the values in "Circuito1$"

2. I **fill the new Excel File through code** as follows:

   ```
       Dim strInsertIntoExcel As String = ""
   Dim cn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & targetPath & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0'"

   strInsertIntoExcel = "INSERT INTO [Circuito1$] (Fecha,Hora,Valor) values(@date,@time,@values)"

   Using cnn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(cn)
       cnn.Open()
       Dim cant As Integer = 0
       Dim value As Decimal
       While cant < 10

           value = Convert.ToDecimal(cant * DateTime.Now.Second)
           Dim fecha As Object = DateTime.Now
           Using cmd As OleDbCommand = cnn.CreateCommand()
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", "fecha")
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", "daf1")
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@values", value)
               Console.WriteLine(value)
               cmd.CommandText = strInsertIntoExcel
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
           End Using
           cant = cant + 1

       End While


   End Using
   ```

   3. I **verify in the recently updated Excel file the values** in the "Formula$" sheet, but they don't appear updated. But if I go to cell B1, do F2 and then press Enter, formula result is updated with the right values. What I'm expecting as the right behavior is that the formula result is shown updated automatically, without having to press F2 and then Enter.

NOTE: Automatically update is enabled on the workbooks, the template and the generated files.

I can't find out why it is happening, because if fill the values manually, using my keyboard (instead of code), it works fine.

What is causing this behavior?

NOTE: The template file can be downloaded here https://www.dropbox.com/s/duii11fyfh7u2kw/libro.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Have you tried forcing calculation `application.calculate`?

Comment: No, because I'm not using the application object to manipulate the Excel file.

Comment: What do you mean don't use application, what do you use? Do you write to the file without opening excel?

Comment: In point #2 I explain the way I populate values into Excel, I do it through the OleDbCommand

Comment: Sorry,I still don't understand. In which application do you have the code? Do you open the file with the macro, or just populate it?

Comment: I have a vb .net application, I don't need to open the file visually in order to update it, I just do it from the vb .net application, all of that is in the code detailed in the post

Comment: Can that be the reason why your formula doesn't updated? Maybe neither paste in .NET, neither opening trigger calculation. (I'm not an expert in .NET, are other formulas updated automatically?) If you don't want to open excel from .NET, other option could be to refresh from workbook's open event.

Comment: I started to notice this behaviour when I changed my code to use the ace.oledb - before I was using the jet.oledb driver and did not experience any calculation issues. Now I have to open the file afterwards to execute a macro which is doing a Application.CalculateFull. Not very nice, though...